# Where to find documentation on Android Studio external libraries?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, github

I apologize if this question is too broad. I am looking to implement the external library [Floating Action Button](https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton) for my Android Studio project, but I am unable to find the documentation for the methods in Java that I should be using to implement its functionality, such as expanding the FAB into several other FABs, as shown in the Screenshot portion of the link.

I have already added the dependency to my gradle and `com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton` header to my XML layout file.

The reason I am asking is because I've come across several libraries on Github that have minimal descriptions and no documentation. How does someone learn the methods and classes for external libraries like this without them? There must be something I am misunderstanding here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How does someone learn the methods and classes for external libraries like this without them?

Review the source code of [the sample app](https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton/tree/master/sample).

Or, review the source code of [the library](https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton/tree/master/library).

Or, search for `com.github.clans.fab` on your favorite search engine to see if anyone has [a blog post](http://www.viralandroid.com/2016/02/android-floating-action-menu-example.html) or [other sort of article](http://www.devexchanges.info/2016/07/floating-action-menu-in-android.html) on the library.

Comment: Reviewing the source code in the library is exactly what I needed, at least for this library specifically, I don't know how I missed it. Thanks very much.